# ".class expected" while attempting to use returned array

Tags: java, android

I have a file scanner that reads from a file, a bunch of numbers (doubles) and stores them in tmpVal[]. I would then like to pass it to another method (make_abs_val) to get the absolute value of those numbers, so I can print it to a textview and/or write it to a file. What I'm not sure about is using the new array after I abs value it... I'm getting ".class expected" . . .

```html
//get from file into first array
//this is all part of the mainActivity
while(fileScn.hasNext()){
            val = fileScn.nextDouble();
            tmpVal[arrayNum] = val;
            arrayNum++;

        }

// this is where I'm getting the error, not sure what to do.
make_it_abs(tmpVal[]);

//output to textview
for (int a = 0; a < arrayNum; a++ ){
            txtVw.setText(String.format("%.2f", /*Not sure what variable to use */) + "\n");
        }

//required method to get abs val
                             
public double[] make_it_abs(double orig[]){
        for(int i=0; i < orig.length; i++){
            orig[i] = Math.abs(orig[i]);
        }
        return orig;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace make_it_abs(tmpVal[]) with `make_it_abs(tmpVal)`.

Comment: Getting a "make_it_abs cannot be applied"

Comment: Are you sure tmpVal's type is double[]?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is preceeded by a raw `for-loop` (and you appear to want to index the array `tmpVal`, and you can use `%n` in a format for a new-line). Also, you pass a method an array with the name (no `[]` needed). Something like,

```
    make_it_abs(tmpVal);
    for (int a = 0; a < arrayNum; a++){
        txtVw.setText(String.format("%.2f%n", tmpVal[a]));
    }
} // <-- this is missing

//required method to get abs val                         
public double[] make_it_abs(double orig[]){
    for(int i=0; i < orig.length; i++){
        orig[i] = Math.abs(orig[i]);
    }
    return orig;
}
```

Comment: That extra curly braces is there actually. I did just solve it myself, thanks though!